# This app may not be secure webview error when logging in using google

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am trying to log in using google in a webview in my app. I get the following error (see image attached)

Here's my code

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: backBtnLbl.frame.maxY + 15, width: CGFloat(viewWithWebView.frame.width), height: CGFloat(viewWithWebView.frame.height)))
webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.96, green: 0.96, blue: 0.96, alpha: 1.00)
viewWithWebView.addSubview(webView)
self.view.addSubview(viewWithWebView)
```

[image]